# INHERITANCE LIBRARY

Tags: c, embedded

I'm interested about this. I have a library house.h, which includes a library roof.h. Also I have a library car.h, which includes a library roof.h.

Library roof.h contains next includes (so far written only using as a relief to     explain), e.g.:

```
//this is only for the house.h`
include tile.h
include beam.h
include form_roof_house.h
//this is only for the car.h
include sheet_metal.h
include form_roof_car.h
include modular.h //, etc.
```

Now, my questions is, whether there is a way that my library roof.h knows which library is included here, respectively that my library roof.h knows that library house.h is included here. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using include only for `house.h` or `car.h`, you should not put these in `roof.h` but directly in `house.h` or `car.h`. Having a "parent" header file is good when you have common headers / code that you want to share everywhere.

Comment: Those files look like they are headers, not libraries.  A header is a text file that is included in source files (or other headers) to provide information to the compiler. A library is a collection of object files that can be processed by the linker, along with the object files specific to your program, to create an executable. You should really show syntactically correct `#include` statements. If you got confused because they appear as titles, then you need to type the code as you want it to appear (ignore the preview), then select all the code, and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box.

Comment: Sorry; I'm new here and my questions was only as an example. I will present now what I need. I develop one embedded system for controlling three phase AC motor. I made 44 library, and each library include something. HAL driver include lowest driver, then APP driver include, already mentioned, HAL driver. Ehh now, I think about this, to develop a one universal library, which will be included in all 44 library, only she, and all includes for each 44 library would be located in these universal library, but only problem is that she needs to know, which library is included her.

Comment: And of course, when universal library know which library included her, I will do next:
    #ifdef (one of the 44 library)#include (all necessary library for this library)
    #endif
    #ifdef (second of the 44 libray)
    #include (all necessary library for this library)
    #endif
....... etc

Answer (score 0):

Header files should include header guards ie they will not be included twice. You're alluding to two roof.h files? If they share the same guards the first one will be loaded. `C the language without the preprocessor` has no knowledge of what's happening as files are included etc before their compiled.

Answer (score -1):

Your program design is flawed, because roof needs to be an "abstract base class" that only know about generic roof stuff and that presents an API. Therefore, roof.h should not include any of those headers. Most importantly there should not be a tight coupling between house roof and car roof, that doesn't make any sense, and those two might not even exist in the same program.

Instead, you need to make two new classes that inherit roof, call them for example roof_house and roof_car. Each of them is including roof.h.

From there, you can implement the program design in many ways, depending on how picky you want to be with the OO part of the design. There's not even a need to use OO design (C programmers are often scared about it) but the above mentioned file dependencies must hold.

Avoiding tight coupling is not specific to OO, it is about applying common sense: avoiding fail-cascading bugs, avoiding maintenance problems etc etc.

---

One possible design is to implement polymorphism through function pointers:

**roof.h**

```
typedef struct roof_t roof_t; // forward declaration

typedef void roof_func_t (const roof_t* roof);

typedef struct
{
  roof_func_t* init;
  roof_func_t* draw;
} roof_t;

// functions for public interface:

roof_t* roof_create (const roof_func_t* init, const roof_func_t* draw);

void roof_draw (const roof_t* roof);
```

**roof.c**

```
#include "roof.h"

roof_t* roof_create (const roof_func_t* init, const roof_func_t* draw)
{
  roof_t* roof = malloc(sizeof(roof_t));
  roof->init = init;
  roof->draw = draw;
  return roof;
}

void roof_draw (const roof_t* roof)
{
  roof->draw();
}
```

**roof_house.h**

```
#include "roof.h"

void roof_house_init (const roof_t* roof);
void roof_house_draw (const roof_t* roof);
```

**roof_house.c**

```
#include "roof_house.h"

void roof_house_init (const roof_t* roof)
{
  // whatever needs to go here
}

void roof_house_draw (const roof_t* roof)
{
   // whatever needs to go here
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "roof.h"
#include "roof_house.h"

roof_t* my_roof = roof_create(roof_house_init, roof_house_draw);
roof_draw(my_roof);
```

This is of course just a rough example. Private encapsulation etc needs to be implemented and there might be need for a way for the inherited classes to add their own member variables etc.

Needless to say, each header file should always have header guards.